# Query for records with empty array with Rails and Postgres array type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

How can I query for all records with an empty array, using the Postgres array data type?

```
 create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "email", limit: 255, default: "",null: false
   t.string   "roles", default: [], array: true
 end
```

I want to query for all records with an empty roles array.

Tried `User.where("roles @> ?", '{}')` but that did not work (returned 0 records).

Comment: have you tried just compare to `nil` or  `[]`?

Comment: you did create a record right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is the syntax you can use:

```
User.where("roles = '{}'")
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `User.where("roles = '[]'")` ? Since @chrismanderson defined the default to be `[]` not `{}`.

Comment: @wuliwong that was indeed the case for me

Comment: Using curly braces should be the working solution following the Postgres Documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html

Comment: @wuliwong Does not work in postres 10. Gives error:

`PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "[]"`
Example with curly braces work fine

Answer (score 3):

You can also do: `User.where(roles: [])`

I'm using Rails 5.2 (although the syntax may have been introduced earlier). I realize this is an old question, but in case anyone finds it from a Google search (like me).

Comment: This approach did not work for me ('rails', '~> 5.2.0').

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
where("roles = ?", '{null}')
```